# InfoPath forms, the ability to do a staggered completion

Tags: list, infopath

I've got an InfoPath 2013 form which has three sections. Each section needs a separate approval. I'm going to use different views to lock off each section when it's been submitted.

There is a two - three day time lapse in the process between the sections being submitted and approved. So what's the best way to do build in the ability to partially submit an InfoPath form and come back to it? Would it be easier to do three linked forms which submit to the same list/library or is there a slicker way of doing it? I'm using SharePoint 2010.